# Angular 7 with WebPack, making request with URL length of 11962 characters is not working

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using Angular 7.2.
For the Webpack dev server I am using a get request with 11632 length. This is not allowed through Webpack Dev Server.
I have configured server as:

```js
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "<<app>>:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json",
            "port": 4200
          },
          "configurations": {
            "prod": {
              "browserTarget": "<<app>>:build:prod"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "<<app>>:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
```

My proxy configuration is:

```js
{
  "/<<TomCatAppName>>/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8989/<<TomCatAppName>>",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/<<TomCatAppName>>/*": ""
    }
  },
    "/assets/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8989/assets",
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel": "debug",
      "pathRewrite": {
        "^/assets/*": ""
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: The best, safe thing to do is to use much shorter URLs. Browsers and servers will not accept such long URLs.

Comment: This is my server, and I am using graphql request. In that it is possible to have such a large request.